# diff says files are different even after sync with rsync

Tags: sync, rsync, bash-scripting, diff

To synchronise two directories, I run

```
diff -r -q path/to/dir1 path/to/dir2 1>/dev/null
if [[ $? == "0" ]]
then
  echo "Directories are exact copies of each other"
else
  rsync -av --delete path/to/dir1 path/to/dir2
fi
```

However, if a run the script again diff says that the directories are still different.

Yet, when creating two empty folders `test` and `sync`, diff says they are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need:

```
diff -r -q path/to/dir1 path/to/dir2/dir1 1>/dev/null
if [[ $? == "0" ]]
then
  echo "Directories are exact copies of each other"
else
  rsync -av --delete path/to/dir1 path/to/dir2
fi
```

As rsync will create a new folder `dir1` in `dir2` to really preserve the whole `dir1` folder and not only it's content.

Comment: How can I make rsync to synchronise content of dir, not creating a new sub-dir?

Comment: @Narusan You would need `rsync -ar --delete path/to/dir1 path/to/dir2`, -r stands for --recursive.For more information refer to rsync's manual (To open the manual use `man rsync`.).